# How to calculate $\int\frac{1}{x + 1 + \sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 5}}\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to calculate $$\int\frac{1}{x + 1 + \sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 5}}dx?$$ I really don't know how to attack this integral. I tried $u=x^2 + 4x + 5$ but failed miserably. Help please.

Comment: Two ideas: $x+2=\tan u$, or multiply by the conjugate. I am pretty sure that the first one will work :)

Comment: The change of variables $x=-2+\frac{t-t^{-1}}{2}$ will transform this into an integral of a (very simple) rational function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int\frac1{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+4x+5}}\ dx&=\int\frac1{x+1+\sqrt{(x+2)^2+1}}\ dx\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{[1]}}=\int\frac{\sec^2y}{\sec y+\tan y-1}\ dy\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{[2]}}=\int\frac{\sec y}{\sin y-\cos y+1}\ dy\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{[3]}}=\int\frac{1+t^2}{t(1+t)(1-t^2)}\ dt\\
&\stackrel{\color{red}{[4]}}=\int\left[\frac1{t}-\frac1{2(t+1)}-\frac1{2(t-1)}-\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}\right]\ dt.
\end{align}
The rest is yours.

---

**Notes :**

$\color{red}{[1]}\;\;\;$Put $x+2=\tan y\;\Rightarrow\;dx=\sec^2y\ dy$.

$\color{red}{[2]}\;\;\;$Multiply by $\dfrac{\cos y}{\cos y}$.

$\color{red}{[3]}\;\;\;$Use [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution), $\tan\frac{y}{2}=t$.

$\color{red}{[4]}\;\;\;$Use [partial fractions decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Comment: @TunkFey. This is a beautiful answer ! Cheers  :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. I got the idea from chubakueno's comment and I answered it while watching WC'14, Brazil vs Chile. I missed the goal. Hahaha...

Comment: Am I missing something?  Where does that fourth power in the denominator in the first step come from?

Comment: The name "Weierstrass substitution" is probably a misnomer since Fred Rickey reports going through all of Weierstrass' writings looking for it, without success.  But he found it in Euler's writings a century before Weierstrass.  It is spread by Stewart's calculus book. I have a private communication from Stewart saying he didn't invent the terminology himself, but without specificity about where he got it.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int\frac{1}{x+1+\sqrt{x^{2}+4x+5}}dx=\int\frac{(x+1)-\sqrt{x^{2}+4x+5}}{-2x-4}$$
$$=\frac{-1}{2}\int\frac{x+1}{x+2}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+4x+5}}{x+2}dx$$

The first integral can be dealt with but noticing:

$$\int\frac{x+1}{x+2}dx=\int1dx-\int\frac{1}{x+2}dx$$

The second integral is dealt with as follows:

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+4x+5}}{x+2}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{(x+2)^{2}+1}}{x+2}dx$$

Let $x+2=\tan(u)$ then:

$$\int\frac{\sec^{3}(u)}{\tan(u)}du=\int\sec^{2}(u)\csc(u)=\tan(u)\csc(u)+\int\csc(u)du$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac1{x+1+\sqrt{x^2+4x+5}}=-\frac{x+1-\sqrt{x^2+4x+5}}{2(x+2)}$$

$$=-\frac{x+2-1-\sqrt{x^2+4x+5}}{2(x+2)}$$

$$=-\frac12+\frac1{2(x+2)}+\frac{\sqrt{(x+2)^2+1}}{2(x+2)}$$

Setting $x+2=\tan y,$
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{(x+2)^2+1}}{(x+2)}\ dx=\int\frac{\sec y}{\tan y}\sec^2y\ dy$$

$$=\int\frac{dy}{\cos^2y\sin y}=\int\frac{\sin y\ dy}{\cos^2y(1-\cos^2y)}$$

Set $\displaystyle\cos y=u$

Answer (score 2):

**Another approach :** (The shortest one)

Using [Euler substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) by setting $t-x=\sqrt{x^2+4x+5}$, we will obtain 
$x=\dfrac{t^2-5}{2t+4}$ and $dx=\dfrac{t^2+4t+5}{2(t+2)^2}\ dt$, then the integral turns out to be
$$
-\int\dfrac{t^2+4t+5}{2(t+2)(t+3)}\ dt=\int\left[\frac1{t+3}-\frac1{2(t+2)}-\frac12\right]\ dt.
$$
The last part uses [partial fraction decomposition](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+%28t%5E2%2B4t%2B5%29%2F%28-2%28t%2B2%29%28t%2B3%29%29) and the rest should be easy to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

With $y=x+2$, rewrite the integral
\begin{align}
I=&\int\frac{1}{x + 1 + \sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 5}}\ dx
=\int \frac{1}{y - 1 + \sqrt{y^2 + 1}}\ dy\\
=&\ \frac12\int \bigg( 1+\frac{y-{\sqrt{y^2+1}+1}}{y+{\sqrt{y^2+1}-1}}\bigg)\ \frac{dy}y=\frac12\ln|y|+\frac12 \int \frac{1+t^2}{t(1+t)^2}\ dt
\end{align}
where the Euler substitution $t= \frac{\sqrt{y^2+1}-1}y $ is applied. As a result
$$I= \frac12\ln|ty|+\frac1{1+t}
$$